# Getting location updates in android app

Tags: android, jsp, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if i could create an android application which procures the mobile's location for every 150 meteres and update my java web-server.

All i want for the android app to do is to update the details for every 150 mts and thats it and i'm not expecting any response or acknowledgement from we server.

Can this be done by communicating to a jsp or a servlert or any other technique.

What's the best approach for getting the location details even in moving vehicles and updating the details to my web server which would maintain the details in a database.

Can anyone provide any samples and suggest the best methodology to do the same in the most time efficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be register a service, define a custom location listener. In the implementation override the onLocationChanged() and you can get the location (lat, long) tuple and you could probably update the server with a GET/POST request. Take a look at the reference code.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    String Text = "Location : (" + loc.getLatitude() +","+ loc.getLongitude() + ")";
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have any doubt. You can adjust the frequency of update requests.

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference between using a web service(REST) or a normal jsp/servlet in the communication of the location to the server.How is setting up of a webservice helpful in this context.And how to adjust the frequency of the updates.

Comment: It is just that, what ever you use on the server side make a request on the "device location changed event", to tell the server to update the location of the device. I don't know anything about JSP/Servlet. To adjust the frequency, you should use an algorithm to find if the change is significant or not. If you are interested, I would put that code also for reference. By the word "service" I referred to android services and not a web-service : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Yes please.Can you please post the code for checking if there is a significant change from the previously recorded location.

Comment: There is a documentation for this also : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html
Can you check that out?

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing locations with that frequency will likely drain the users battery. But anyways.

Joe Lapenna who wrote a foursquare client has a location class which provides sane logic on grabbing the most accurate location giving different sources and parameters.

http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/location/BestLocationListener.java

Google and the Android Developers have written about the most efficient way to retrieve location updates in this blog post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: What if battery problems werent an issue but the new location at every 150mts should be procured no matter what.Then what methodology can i take.Usually what's the avg min time required to procure the phone's own location using in an android app.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the full source code for such an application on http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/. The homepage for the application is on http://mytracks.appspot.com/. This is a good starting point for developing such applications.

The app stores your tracks completly on your device and allows the export to SD card or to Google Docs or to Google maps. You can easily extend the application to send the track to your own server application.

Do not send every single position to the server, because this costs to much ressources. When you use Java on the server, it will be always a servlet. I recommend to use REST with one of the available libraries.

Comment: The mytracks is focussed on getting the places around the phone .It would be helpful if i could get the phones own location and just transfer it to my web server and thats it.And can java work with the location data like testing it whether the location received would be closer or far to a pre-recorded location.How can i go about this.

Comment: No, mytracks records your tracks and enables you to upload or view the track. This application includes all the techniques your are asking for and is a good starting point for learning to develop a location based app for your own.